# Enzyme immobilization: Factors that help or hurt success

Tags: molecular-biology, enzymes

Are there any factors to consider that can help / hurt the chance to get a successful immobilized enzyme catalyst?

i.e. The relative attractiveness of a live host synthesis vs an immobilized enzyme.

Specifically, the product of interest is a secondary metabolite of MW approx. & the host of choice is S. Cervesae. The transformation is a single step, catalyzed by a single, known enzyme with the gene coding for it approx. 2000 base pairs.